# Is it possible to highlight the minimum value in a table on Gsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am currently compiling a table of pace per minute on this Gsheet.

I am looking to conditionally format the cells to highlight the minimum and maximum but cannot seem to find a formula for this online.

Would anyone know the formula for min and max on this section?

Thank you

[image: Here's my current attempt at 'Min']

Answer (score 1):

You should 2 rules

```
=I12=MIN($I$12:$L$16)
```

and

```
=I12=MIN($I$12:$L$16)
```

Adjust your ranges accordingly paying attention to the dollar sign `$`

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.